# how to set server time stamp with firestore admin nodejs sdk?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

```
const firebase = require('@firebase/app').default;
require('@firebase/firestore')

const admin = require('firebase-admin')
const functions = require('firebase-functions')

// initialize the admin SDK...    

exports.setUpdatedDate = functions.firestore.document('/foos/{fooId}/bars/{barId}')
    .onCreate(event => {
      admin.firestore().collection('foos').doc( event.params.fooId )
            .set({
                updatedDate: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
            }, {merge:true})
    })
```

Running the function shell above and I got:

```
Cannot encode type ([object Object]) to a Firestore Value
at Function.encodeValue (...\functions\node_modules\@google-cloud\firestore\src\document.js:772:11
```

so how to set server time stamp with firestore admin nodejs sdk?

Comment: It looks like you didn't initialize the admin SDK.  Also, it looks like you're requiring client side SDKs. Those don't apply for Cloud Functions. You just need firebase-admin.

Comment: @DougStevenson thx, I did actually, just didn't post it. :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use `admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`.

API docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.firestore.FieldValue
Example usage: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/blob/master/test/integration/firestore.js#L61

Comment: Thank you! In your opinion updating last updated date is best done by cloud function or client's transaction?

Comment: I feel like that is something that should be updated along with the client transaction.

Comment: Usage link is broken

Comment: I´m currently using this function and it´s returning me an empty value

Comment: Here's the updated link for the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.FieldValue